# Using C struct in C#

Tags: c#, c, struct

I have a C header file with:

```
typedef struct CallbackData
{
    Int 32          linkType;                   
    string          strUrl;                                   
} CallbackData
```

I have a function in C#:

```
private Int32 CallbackFunction(IntPtr intPtr, Int32 callbackData, Int32 commandInfo, object callbackObject)
    {
    if (callbackObject.GetType() == typeof(CallbackData))
    {
           var callbackData = (CallbackData) callbackObject;
           callbackData.strUrl = "Something";
           return 0;
    }
    if (callbackData == 283)
    {
           return 0;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(callbackData);
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to import the `CallbackData` struct into C# and then check to see if the `callbackObject` that is passed into the `CallbackFunction` is of the `CallbackData` type. Then I would like to set the strUrl of the `callbackObject`.

I have created a struct like so in another C# file:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CallbackData
{
    Int32 linkType;
    string strUrl;

}
```

VS is saying that "`object` does not contain a definition for `strUrl` and no extension method `strUrl` accepting a first argument of type `object` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". How do I edit strUrl of the object if it is of type `CallbackData`?

**EDIT:** Changed how I was casting the incoming param.

Answer (score 0):

Anything is declared as `private` by default in C#, so you need to define your struct like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CallbackData
{
    public Int32 linkType;
    public string strUrl;
}
```